# Log Laravel with artisan output

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with Laravel and I trying to do a log of some function output with this Log function:

> Log::warning("some message")

But if I want to write in console and log file I need to write two times the same message with different function like this:

> Log::warning("some message")  //This work good for log file
>
> dump("some message") //This work good for artisan console output

There is some function that allow me only use one of both?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Laravel events to integrate this functionality without requiring any change to the way you currently log information.

Add a listener for the `Illuminate\Log\Events\MessageLogged` event, and within your listener output the log entry to the console *if* the request has come from the console -- using [runningInConsole()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L531).

1. [Register a new listener](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/events#registering-events-and-listeners) called `MessageLoggedListener`, e.g:

   ```
   protected $listen = [
       'Illuminate\Log\Events\MessageLogged' => [
           'App\Listeners\MessageLoggedListener',
       ],
   ];
   ```
2. Generate your listener with `php artisan event:generate`
3. Add the event handler to your listener:

   ```
   /**
   * Handle the event.
   *
   * @param  MessageLogged  $event
   * @return void
   */
   public function handle(MessageLogged $event)
   {
       if (app()->runningInConsole()) {
           $output = new ConsoleOutput();
           $output->writeln("<error>{$event->message}</error>");
       }
   }
   ```

That's it! You're now ready to test the functionality. From a console command log a message, e.g:

```
    public function handle()
    {
        Log::error('Hello world! This is an error.');
    }
```

This is the output you'll see:

```
$ php artisan command
Hello world! This is an error.
```

And within your log file you'll see:

```
[2018-01-15 16:55:46] local.WARNING: Hello world! This is an error.
```

You can improve the functionality by adding different output styles, for example you may wish to use `error` for errors and `info` for info. You can read about styling your output [here in the Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/coloring.html).